# Horse light/heavy [drain / strain / labour / weight]?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Is this a thing in english? I'm trying to express that there are different conditions for horses under light/medium/heavy stress as well as when a horse is calm?

I don't know how to say this but basically the horse has either a lot of work out (training, running around, racing, jumping ...)

The translator gives me all kidns of options as well as a dictionary but I don't know what to use in this case?

Or perhaps something completely different?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Clarification - Can I say: This treatment is good for horses under/at [light/heavy/...] load? Do I use under or at and do I use load or is there a better way to describe this for a sport horse (by load I mean how much the horse trains and does exercises and racing) not a horse physically pulling a cart or something.

Comment: I don' really understand what you're asking about here, but it may be relevant to note that a horse / athlete / etc. might undertake ***intensive** training* as opposed to ***light** exercise*.

Comment: I tried clarifying my question I hope it helps. I'm sorry I can't properly express myself it's kinda difficult for me in this case.

Comment: I suspect your problems are mainly being caused by you trying to translate something *word-by-word*. In English it's natural enough to speak of, say, *engine performance under heavy load*, where *heavy load* can be seen as somewhat "metaphoric". In terms of actual *weight*, that load might be relatively light, but we could still refer to the engine as being "under heavy load" if it was required to pull that load up a very steep hill, for example. But that "metaphoric" aspect doesn't work so well with a horse or other pack-animal, which is more closely associated with the *literal* sense.

Comment: Yeah I understand that word-by-word translation is not the way to go in many cases. But My problem is that I don't know the word and that's what I'm looking for. Dictionaries give several options (as stated in my original post) and I don't know which is used with horses in english.

Comment: I you train your horse hard or just give him some light exercises there is a word describbing the codnition of said horse. But I don't know which word is properly used in this context.

Comment: Let me rephrase it in a slightly different way.
You have three kinds of special meals (A, B, C) for your horse. One for a horse after a light exercise (you just walk around with him and then feed him A). One for a horse after a tougher exercise (you ride him but still just walking might be a fast walk and then feed him B). Finally, one for a horse after a race (horse is super exhausted after a race, you feed him C). How do you describe the first, second and third horse options if you want to use light *something*, medium *something*, heavy *something* or similar adjectives?

Comment: I don't know if there's a "caring for horses" site within SO, but I think what you're looking for here might well involve "domain-specific" terminology that's not really relevant to ELL in general. Straight off I can see the scope for major confusion as regards whether the horse is *accustomed* to being physically taxed (as part of its normal day-to-day existence), or has just finished a one-off activity involving extreme effort.

Comment: I once did some work for a veterinarian who worked in horse racing; he referred to the horses as **equine athletes** rather than **sport horses**. It is a common term, though here **sport horse** is also used: http://www.vet.upenn.edu/veterinary-hospitals/NBC-hospital/services/sports-medicine

Comment: I'm not looking for a horse specific work. I might have expressed myself wrong sorry guys for any confusion :(.

The other answer had a word that is at the right direction probably:

"This treatment is good for horses after..a light workout/hard workout/"

Workout. Could I use it like this and/or is there anything similar?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some suggestions that are grammatically correct and I think convey the meaning that you intend. However, you might need to give examples of the specific levels of activity that you are referring to.

This treatment is good for horses accustomed to heavy workouts.

This treatment is good for highly exercised horses.

This treatment works well for racing-conditioned horses.

This treatment is appropriate for horses at the highest fitness levels only.

Comment: I probably expressed myself wrong again. But you gave me a good idea I hope.

First of all, sentence: This treatment is good for horses under/at [light/heavy/...] load? Can apply to anytghing, humans, squirrels, whales. So no need to be horse specific. :-).

I think what I'm looking for is this (from your answers):
This treatment is good for horses after..a light workout/hard workout/. Though I don't know what to put in between the light and hard?

Is this ok?

Comment: I would say "under" a heavy load rather than "at" a heavy load. A "heavily-burdened" horse or mule would be carrying a heavy or large load.

Comment: As for qualifying the workout with adjectives, consider this:


A "light" or "easy" workout, or a "low-stress" workout. A "moderate" or "average" workout. A "heavy," "hard," or "rigorous" workout.

Hope that gives you some ideas!